# CSS, Left and Right borders override part of top one

Tags: html, css

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CM33V/1/
Is it possible without additional html elements remove grey lines from left and right borders on red one?

Code is simple:

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:15px solid #C90110;
}
```

This code is used in email html layout, so i am not sure it is okay to workaround with shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, not for the purpose you want at least (on a web page easy!)

If you are doing this as an email template, and for cross-(browser, email client - insert appropriate word here) you should use two separate divs anyway (in fact TABLES(shock horror) are better for emails in most cases!)

Email is a really tricky one to get right so stick the the simplest method - two divs, one red, one white with left, right and top borders - it will work across the most email clients that way.

Answer below covers how to do it on web so +1 for that one (would give +2 as he did a fiddle but cant do that :-P)

Answer (score 4):

Im afraid if you want a fix for HTML email, you're pretty much stuck with having to add additional elements, as this is the way borders work in CSS. For browsers however..

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CM33V/3/)

....there is one way you could fix it without *technically* adding anything to your HTML (but only because `:pseudo` elements arent added to the DOM), its a bit cheeky though:

```
div {    
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border-top:15px solid #C90110;
    position:relative;

}
div:after{
    position:absolute;    
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```